# android idle time

Tags: android, time, interaction

I want to make an application which when it is on "idle state" it must stop doing something. Application enters in idle when user doesn't interact with the application for a number of seconds (ex. 50). Are there some android classes for this or how to do this in a simpler way?

Comment: What exactly is your application doing until being switched to idle ?

Comment: I have many activities for reading some stuff, an activity with a list, an option activity... just usual stuff

Comment: so whats exactly do you want to stop? If you have no threads and no background work you app is, by all meaning, already idling...

Comment: I want to stop some requests made to a server

Answer (score 2):

> Application enters in idle when user doesn't interact with the application for a number of seconds (ex. 50)

There is no built-in concept of "idle" in Android, other than the device going into sleep mode. You can watch for `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` broadcast `Intents`, but that will be for the whole system, not just your application.

Comment: but the user may change his phone's settings so that his screen can go off after 30 minutes so this doesn't help me... One solution is to make listeners for key press or text edit or click listener bit it's not an elegant solution...

Comment: @gabi: Get rid of the "idle" requirement, then. Solve whatever problem that you are trying to solve some other way.

Comment: it can be done, android os does that. I just wanna know how... finally I think I will look in android os code

Comment: @gabi: Just because the OS can do something does not mean that an SDK application can do something. Get rid of the "idle" requirement. Solve whatever problem that you are trying to solve some other way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no "background" task processing, you really have to understand the Android Activity lifecycle. You don't have to care about your application going "idle". You have to always keep in mind that your application can be put to sleep by the system AT ANY TIME.

Really read [carefully the developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle).